# For each positive integer n, define s(n) to equal the sum of the digits of n. The number of integers n with 100 ≤ n ≤ 999 and 7 ≤ s(n) ≤ 11 is S.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, generating-functions

So we have a question that goes

For each positive integer n, define s(n) to equal the sum of the digits of n. For
example, s(2023) = 2 + 0 + 2 + 3. The number of integers n with 100 ≤ n ≤ 999 and
7 ≤ s(n) ≤ 11 is S. What is the integer formed by the rightmost two digits of S?

Do we use a generating function to solve this and on a related note how does one find out a generating function for any given problem. If I see that I want to find lets say the number of sets divisible by 5 and there is a generating function to solve it how do I find it for any arbitrary  problem. Is it by chance or what.

Comment: How familiar are you with generating functions? With a passing familiarity, you should be able to start writing something for the first part. EG What is the function for what you described (removing conditions as needed)? What exponents are you interested in? What are their coefficients? $\quad$ For the second part, use the roots of unity to find the sum of coefficients that are 0 mod 5. If this is the first time you're dealing with it, think about how to find the sum for even/odd exponents first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My first instinct looking at this is to treat it as a stars-and-bars question.  Just remember that the largest digit is $9$ and so we can't allow for scenarios where one of the digits is ten nor where one of the digits is eleven.

Comment: @Jochen Your solution would be the GF approach that I think OP is asking about. Not sure why you deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

Break into cases based on the specific sum.  Apply stars-and-bars and temporarily ignore that ten and eleven are not valid digits.  We will subtract the bad cases later.

To have a diophantine sum $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ with $x_1\geq 1$ and $x_2,x_3\geq 0$, this is solved with stars-and-bars.  First, make a change of variable $y_1=x_1-1$ and consider $y_1+x_2+x_3$ instead.  There will be a total of $\binom{(n-1)+3-1}{3-1}$ valid outcomes.

We would have then $\binom{8}{2}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{11}{2}+\binom{12}{2}$ but we will have included a few incorrect outcomes which can be easily counted by hand.

Letting $A$ represent the digit for ten and $B$ the digit for eleven, we will have accidentally counted $A00,~B00,~A10,~A01,~1A0,$ and $10A$ so we need to remove six from our answer to get a final total of:

$$\binom{8}{2}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{11}{2}+\binom{12}{2}-6=224$$